# Wireless access point invalid password

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

I’m trying to set up a wireless access point to extend the range of my router but I ran into some problems.

What I did was the following:

1. Check main router IP address and wireless channel: 192.168.0.1, channel 11
2. Reset my old router (a Sagem F3464) that I want to use as access point
3. Plug the router into my pc and surf to its IP address 192.168.1.1
4. Configure the router: turn off DHCP, add WPA2 password, set IP address to 192.168.0.2, set gateway to 192.168.0.1, set wireless channel to 1
5. Unplug router from PC, plug one of its LAN ports into an outlet with a power link adapter (which connects it with the main router).
6. I can see the new Wifi network on my PC, enter the password and I am connected. Everything works, and my connection is 10 times faster as before (my main router is on the first floor and I'm on the second)! Except… when I disconnect and reconnect I get “invalid password”. Now suddenly it doesn’t work anymore. Turning the router off and turning it then on again does not fix the problem. Resetting the router and following the above steps does, except that again I can only connect once. After that I get “invalid password”.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: windows? Sounds like it's not remembering the password. Tried deleting all the saved networks, then connect once & remembering the correct password? Doesn't have anything to do with the router, does it?

Comment: I tried OSX, Windows and Android. Yes, I tried that too. I don't know, I don't have another one to test with.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it WAS the router. I found another old router (Gigaset SX762) which I used as wireless access point and the problem went away.